# viewModelScope.launch и callbackFlow

Tags: kotlin

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться со скопами, делаю патерн MVI не могу понять почему нужно оборачивать вызываемые методы еще одним launch {}. Если не сделать обертку для  repository.registerWithEmailAndPassword то интент поймается только 1 раз, дальше глухо как будто Интенты больше не поступают. Не уверен что так делать правильно, с оберткой в launch работает но хотелось узнать как это правильно сделать и как это работает.

Нужно ли что-то писать в awaitClose {} если используешь callbackFlow с viewModelScope? По идеи когда ляжет viewModelScope он должен за собой утащить все остальное правильно?

ViewModel

```
val userIntent = Channel<RegisterIntent>(Channel.UNLIMITED)

private val _state = MutableStateFlow<RegisterStates>(RegisterStates.Idle)
val state: StateFlow<RegisterStates>
    get() = _state

init {
    handleIntent()
}

 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun handleIntent() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userIntent.consumeAsFlow().collect { intent ->
            when (intent) {
                is RegisterIntent.Idle -> {
                }
                is RegisterIntent.RegisterWithEmailAndPassword -> {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        repository.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                            intent.name,
                            intent.email,
                            intent.password,
                            intent.profileImage
                        ).collect { authData ->
                            when (authData) {
                                UserAuthData.Success -> {
                                    _state.value = RegisterStates.Success
                                }
                                is UserAuthData.Fail -> {
                                    _state.value = RegisterStates.Fail(authData.e)
                                }
                                else -> {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository

```
override fun registerWithEmailAndPassword(
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    profileImage: Uri?
): Flow<UserAuthData> =
    callbackFlow {
        val onCompleteListener = OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
        ..........
                    sendBlocking(UserAuthData.Success)
                } else {
                    sendBlocking(UserAuthData.Success)
                }
            }
        }
        val onFailureListener = OnFailureListener {
            sendBlocking(UserAuthData.Fail(it))
        }
        try {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener)
                .addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            sendBlocking(UserAuthData.Fail(e))
        }
        awaitClose {
        }
    }
```

View

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
                registerViewModel.userIntent.send(
                    RegisterIntent.RegisterWithEmailAndPassword(
                        userName,
                        userEmail,
                        userPassword,
                        profileImg
                    )
                )
            }
```

Comment: а зачем тут callbackFlow? там же коллбеки вызываются одни раз, а не потоком, используйте suspend функцию и suspendCancellableCoroutine

Comment: хотел как лучше, вырезал код чтобы легче читалось, надо было видимо весь давать) Там используется Firebase он на калбеках

Comment: я понял, что это фаербейз, callbackFlow там не нужен, можно не заморачиваться и использовать await из https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Comment: спасибо за await жизнь стала чуть проще,
может еще кому-то пригодятся примеры
https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/realtimedatabase/products/ProductsRepository.kt